# How to store the text at only particular indexpath

Tags: ios

I does't getting one thing .

i need to store the text at the particular indexpath.That means i have tableview.In the tableviewcell i have textfield.Once i typed the text but the problem is while scroll the tableview the typed text is displaying in the texfield of other cell.How to fix it?

currently in the viewcontroller-

cellforrow index i have button acton .The tableviewcell code is below.

```
   func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
       texttype.text = ""


    }
    func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
               return true
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

   self.TextAction(texttype)

    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {


        return true;
    }



    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        return true;

    }
```

And in the cellforrow index:-

```
    cell.textadd = {[weak self] in

                if let i = self?.tableview.indexPath(for: $0) {


                    print("the selected text\(cell.textname ?? "")")

                    print(i)

                    print("the Selected button is \(cell.textname ?? "")")

                    print(i)
                    print(cell.textname)
                    print(indexPath.row)
                    print(indexPath.section)



                    let indexPath1 = self?.tableview.indexPath(for: $0)
                    let text1 = cell.texttype.text
                    print(text1)




                        let model = self?.questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath1!)
                        //                    print(model?.values ?? "")
                        //

                        self?.questionViewModel.setData(atIndex: indexPath1!, text: text1!, Option: model!)


                        cell.setText(Options: model!)

                    if model?.values == "text"{
                      cell.texttype.text = ""

                    }                  else{
                    cell.texttype.text = text1
                    }


//                    let model = self?.questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)
//                    print(model?.values ?? "")
//                    
                     print("Section \(indexPath.section), Row : \(indexPath.row)")

                    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section:indexPath.section);
                    self?.tableview.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)

                    self?.tableView((self?.tableview)!, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)

                    }
                 print(cell.texttype.text ?? "")
                self?.u = 1
            }
```

So how to store the text of the textfield

Answer (score 0):

you just need to `override` you custom `UITableViewCell` method

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    yourTextfield.text = nil
}
```

this will solve your problem but this will create new problem also when you scroll to your previous typed cell that cell's textField's text also set to nil because of reusing of cell so for that you have to store that text in your model and reassign it `cellForRow` method by safely unwrapping the optional text